# Is it a good idea to change the format of a external drive from FAT32 to NTFS or HFS+?

Tags: filesystems

I just bought an external hard drive of 320 gb. The default format is FAT32 and I was wondering if it is a good idea to format it to a more modern filesystem.

It is only going to be used with a MAC OS X machine, I don't need windows support.

I was considering:

NTFS
HFS+
ZFS

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If it's going to be used with OS X, use the Mac's disk utility to format it HFS+. There's no reason to use NTFS or ZFS if you're using OS X only.

Comment: Not to mention that NTFS has (by default) no write support on OS X, and I don't even know about the current state of ZFS there.

Comment: The best reason to change it is the individual file size limits and other sacrifices made for cross-compatibility in using FAT32. If you're using only one OS with it, use the OS's native filesystem. Makes everything a lot easier.